# Splitting a column by consecutive zeros

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm new to excel and I am struggling to do something very easy. I have a column of unsorted numbers. I want to set all of the numbers above the last two zeros in consecutive rows in the column to zero (and also in another column set all of the numbers below the first two consecutive zeros to zero).

For example, I have highlighted all of the cells in column A that are above the last two consecutive zeros. I want a method (VBA or formula) that will set these cells to zero and create the output in seen in column B.

[image]

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways of doing it but I would be inclined to use a helper cell (say D1) to work out the last row where that row and the next row contain a pair of zeroes:-

```
=MAX(IF((A1:A19+A2:A20)=0,ROW(A1:A19)))
```

(this is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Then enter the following formula in B1:

```
=IF(ROW()<$D$1,0,A1)
```

[image]

If you had negative numbers as well as positive, this would be better in D1:-

```
=MAX(IF((A1:A19=0)*(A2:A20=0),ROW(A1:A19)))
```

Comment: Thanks! It's occurred to me that if you had -1 and +1 say, it would give you a wrong result but is fine for numbers >=0.